# Third parameter of $.post() is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, web-services, post

**I am sending a post request to the REST web service using the following code:**

```
 <script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#logbutton").click(function(event){
        $.post(
        "http://localhost:8080/CredentialsOnDemand/loginexpert/dologin",
        {
          ephone: $("#mobile").val(),  
          epassword: $("#password").val()
        },
        function(data) {
            data = $.parseJSON( data );
            $(".ray").html("$" + data.tag);
            console.log( "You clicked a paragraph!" );
        }
       );
    });
    });
```

The web service gives a JSON response in format below:

```
{"tag":"login","status":true}
```

The call from the jquery code is running i.e. the web service is running fine, but the function that I have created to parse JSON is not working.

NOTE: 
I tried to run this code without providing any value in the text field. The console displayed the json response and also console.log line.  But when I again entered the values into the fields, then it didn't.  I am unable to understand this thing.

Anyone having any idea? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the function just not run, or does it throw an error? $.post will try to guess the response type, so data may already be a JSON object and the $.parseJSON might be messing things up. What does data print as if you console.log it (before the $.parseJSON call)?

Comment: So the documentation shows how to enable an error handler...what does it tell you? What is `$("#logbutton")`? probably need to prevent form submit

Comment: Any errors in developers console?

Comment: I'm not sure you need to parse the response, you can skip the `data = $.parseJSON( data );` line

Comment: i agree with @cl3m. If the server returns json formatted data, there's no need to parse it again.

Comment: Okay, I guess the function is not working at all.  I just saw my console and its empty.  And I tried running the code by removing the Json.parse line, but no success.

Comment: @EricGuan and @cl3m not always true if Content Type header not set properly but adding 4th param for dataType as `'json'` will force the parsing

Comment: Is page reloading? Did you set up an error handler? have you inspected request in browser dev tools network and also looked in console for errors?

Comment: @charlietfl, you're right, but as he said the webservice was okay, I assumed the dataType was set to `JSON`

Answer (score 0):

You could try the more verbose and detailed form using `$.ajax`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#logbutton").click(function(event) {
    var req = {
      ephone: $("#mobile").val(),
      epassword: $("#password").val()
    };
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:8080/CredentialsOnDemand/loginexpert/dologin",
      data: req,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST'
    }).done(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $(".ray").html("$" + data.tag);
      console.log("You clicked a paragraph!");
    }).fail(function(err) {
      console.error(err);
    });
  });
});
```

This will be easier for you to pinpoint where the error is coming from

Comment: `contentType` is incorrect unless you stringify data and OP is expecting json in post body

Comment: Thanks, I was not sure myself. Edited!